# JPQL with subquery to select max count

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpql, named-query

I'm trying to write a jpql query to select the user with the most comments. If two users have the same number of comments I want to select both.

I tried this, something like this:

```
SELECT
  c.user, COUNT(c.id) as commentCount 
FROM 
  Comment c
WHERE
  commentCount = (SELECT MAX(SIZE(user.comments)) FROM User user)
GROUP BY 
  c.user
```

and this:

```
SELECT
  c.user
FROM 
  Comment c
GROUP BY 
  c.user
HAVING
  COUNT(c) = (SELECT MAX(SIZE(user.comments)) FROM User user)
```

Neither approach works. What do I need to do here?

Comment: When you say did not work, you mean it selected only one user when two users had same # of comments?

Comment: Can you try:
select * from ( SELECT
  c.user, COUNT(c.id) as commentCount 
FROM 
  Comment c)s1 where s1.commentCount = (select max (s2.coomentCount) from SELECT
  c.user, COUNT(c.id) as commentCount 
FROM 
  Comment c) s2

Comment: I always get a "could not execute query" because it is somehow misformed. So in the first place I get "Unknown column "jobsCount" in where clause" and in the second that the group by is invalid (when I add the HAVING part). But I'm not aware of how wo write a working version. Already tried many different versions.

Comment: The query results in: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8  
So I have replaced it with s1 and then I got: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 16

Comment: How about:select * from ( SELECT c.user, COUNT(c.id) as commentCount FROM Comment c)s1 where s1.commentCount = (select max (s2.coomentCount) from (SELECT c.user, COUNT(c.id) as commentCount FROM Comment c) s2 )

Comment: I believe JPQL doesn't support star!? You query with the replaced * results in: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 16

Comment: Ok replace the * with s1.user,s1.commentcount

Comment: Yeah, I did. Any it's not working :-/

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution:

```
SELECT
  u
FROM 
  User u
WHERE
  u.comments.size = (SELECT MAX(u2.comments.size) FROM User u2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you are using Oracle:

```
select u from User u where size(u.comments) = (
    select max(count(c.id)) 
    from User u2 inner join u2.comments c 
    group by u2.id
)
```

But MySQL and SQL Server do not support nested aggregate functions, `max(count(c.id))` in this case. It is suggested to use a subquery, but with HQL you cannot have subqueries in a from clause. So I suggest you do this manually, i.e. load all users:

```
select u, size(u.comments)
from User u
```

and loop through the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly I'm using MySQL and I only can create one named query statement. Any other tips?

Comment: You can use a native query.

Answer (score 0):

For any others coming here and wanting to select a max(count()) in jpql and doesn't have an array, (like in the question the comments) take following jpql code into consideration:

```sql
select e.city 
from Employees e
group by e.city 
having count(e.id) >= All(select count(e) from Employees  e group by e.city)
```

full example in a JPA Repository:

```
@Query(value = "select e.city from Employees e group by e.city " +
        "having count(e.id) >= All(select count(e) from Employees  e group by e.city)")
public List<Cities> findCityByMaxEmployeeCount();
```